# recompose withState how to update on props changes

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components, recompose

I have a higher order component that I try to modify a bit (I'm not familiar with recompose).

So thats my component:

```js
<Map mycenter={mycenter}  />
```

I want the map-component to update or to rerendered if the mycenter is updated. I'm trying to modify the code from 
https://github.com/istarkov/google-map-thousands-markers/blob/master/src/Map.js

I made some modifications to the code. First, the map center is set to mycenter. That works.

```js
withState('mapParams', 'setMapParams', ({ mycenter }) => ({ center:mycenter, zoom: 12 })),
```

After that the user can click somewhere and the center will be modified

```js
withHandlers({
    onMapParamsChange: ({ setMapParams }) => ({ center, zoom, bounds }) => {
      setMapParams({ center, zoom, bounds });
      console.log('setMapParams', { center, zoom });
    },
```

Is there a way so that the component rerenders or the center is updated if "mycenter" is updated?

Comment: A classic state management problem. Look into using a library such as mobx or redux. Another solution would be to move the logic up the state tree to a parent so that when triggered it updates the children.. (am i making sense?)

Comment: Like what @archae0pteryx said, instead of creating a local state, lifting the state to a parent or event a global store usually will solve this problem and produce more readable code.

Comment: @archae0pteryx  Yes I’m using redux in my whole application. The mycenter state comes from redux. Im trying to pass the state over to the map component but don’t want to rewrite it.  I guess that would solve that. Right now I’m working with classes and connect them to redux. Not sure how to do it with the HOC map Component.

Answer (score 4):

Currently, the best way is to use lifecycle.
the callback of initial state (`({ mycenter }) => ({ center:mycenter, zoom: 12 })`) happens only once.

```
const enhanceMap = compose(
  withState('mapParams', 'setMapParams', ({ mycenter }) => ({ center: mycenter, zoom: 12 })),
  withStateHandlers({...}),
  lifecycle({
    componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
      if (this.props.mycenter !== nextProps.mycenter)
        this.setState({mapParams: { center: nextProps.mycenter, zoom: 12 }})
    }
  })
)
```

Comment: `componentWillUpdate` is no longer recommended:https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillupdate

You should probably use `componentDidUpdate`.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this don't come too late.

I find transforming props to state a little bit messy..

Right now, recompose allows you to send a function as a parameter for withProps method. You can do something like:

```
withProps( props => ({
  mycenter: props.mycenter,
  zoom: 12,
}))
```

This way, you will propagate your props down to your component, and it will update whenever the props change.

Comment: Hello. I tried this when my context values didn't update. But solution didn't help :(